# SGX DH key exchange

Tags: diffie-hellman, sgx

I'm trying to create a key exchange app using intel's sgx technology.
I used this - https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/709011 page as guidance ,I send all the messages as this site shows but I don't know how to get the key!.
In the end of DH key exchange I should have a mutual key for the site and the server but I'm not sure where he is.
In the function `sgx_dh_initiator_proc_msg3`(as shown in the buttom of the site) there is a key called 'aek', is this the mutual key?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The agreed DH Key is on both `Msg2` and `Msg3`.

The last executed methods on a DH session establishment on SGX are:

- `sgx_dh_responder_proc_msg2` on the *responder* side, and
- `sgx_dh_initiator_proc_msg3` on the *initiator* side.

Therefore, *they extract the Agreed Key from the message they are processing*.

The output of these methods is:

- the AEK key: `sgx_key_128bit_t`, and
- the Peer identity: `sgx_dh_session_enclave_identity_t`.